# RowReduction: Wolfram Alpha vs Mathematica

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to put in row reduced echelon form the following matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -0.1 & 0.1 & 2 \\
 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.7 \\
 0 & 0.5 & 6.7 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
I did the calculations by hand, and being a fairly simple matrix to reduce, I wanted to test it out in Mathematica, using

```
RowReduce[{{-0.1, 0.1, 2}, {0.3, 0.2, 0.7}, {0, 0.5, 6.7}}]
```

which agrees with my result. I also tried in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RowReduce%5B%7B%7B-0.1,+0.1,+2%7D,+%7B0.3,+0.2,+0.7%7D,+%7B0,+0.5,+6.7%7D%7D%5D), keeping the same input,
however, I get an "incorrect result", which is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0. & 0. \\
 0 & 1 & 0. \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
I noticed that there is a  dot next to some of the $0$s, so I am assuming there are some rounding errors being made. So I tried [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RowReduce%5B%7B%7B-1%2F10,+1%2F10,+2%7D,+%7B3%2F10,+2%2F10,+7%2F10%7D,+%7B0,+5%2F10,+67%2F10%7D%7D%5D) and it worked.

My question is, why is mathematica able to work with greater precision than Wolfram Alpha, even though the function being called is the same?

---

I am aware that this question does not involve solely Mathematica, however since the function is the same for both I wanted to understand the how each handled this.

Comment: I work on alpha, just reported this as a bug.

Comment: The (2,3) element of the original input matrix is 0; however, where you say "So I tried this" the (2,3) element of the given matrix is equal to 7/10 - not 0.    So one shouldn't expect the same answer upon row reduction.

Comment: I typed the original matrix wrong. I missed that. Thank you for pointing it out. I’ll edit

Comment: @JasonB. I'm not convinced it's a bug.  Please see my answer. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ilian points out, this is caused by the underlying Mathematica version (along with the OS?):

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 2, 2017)"
> ```

```
RowReduce[{{-0.1, 0.1, 2}, {0.3, 0.2, 0.7}, {0, 0.5, 6.7}}]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0., 0.}, {0, 1, 0.}, {0, 0, 1}}
> ```

@MichaelE2 argues that this is not a bug. While I agree this is not a *Mathematica* bug, I do consider it a *Wolfram|Alpha* bug. W|A should be treating `6.7` as `67/10` in this input, while Mathematica should not.

I suppose the logic is that the average W|A user shouldn't need to understand the nuances of machine precision, or what machine precision is for that matter. *Mathematically* `6.7` is `67/10`, and W|A should understand this here.

Comment: I agree with you

Answer (score 4):

I think the reason is the underlying version of Mathematica (the result may also depend on the platform to some extent).

Using 64-bit  Linux for example (since that's what Alpha servers run), this example works better in version 10 and later:

```
$Version                                                                            

(* 11.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017) *)

RowReduce[{{-0.1, 0.1, 2}, {0.3, 0.2, 0.7}, {0, 0.5, 6.7}}]                         

(* {{1, 0., -6.6}, {0, 1, 13.4}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

while version 9 produces the suboptimal result

```
$Version                                                                            

(* 9.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 7, 2013) *)

RowReduce[{{-0.1, 0.1, 2}, {0.3, 0.2, 0.7}, {0, 0.5, 6.7}}]
```

> RowReduce::luc: Result for RowReduce of badly conditioned matrix 
>           {{-0.1, 0.1, 2.}, {0.3, 0.2, 0.7}, {0., 0.5, 6.7}}
>            may contain significant numerical errors.

```
(* {{1, 0., 0.}, {0, 1, 0.}, {0, 0, 1}} *)
```

Note also the appropriate warning message, although it is not visible when using Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it depends also on the platform

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a bug.  First, keep in mind that the floating-point number `0.1` is not the same as `1/10`:

```
SetPrecision[0.1, Infinity]
% - 1/10
(*
  3602879701896397/36028797018963968
  1/180143985094819840
*)
```

The "fairly simple" row reduction referred to in the OP is, I suppose, achieved by treating the decimals as exact numbers. But that is not what one gets by treating them as 64-bit binary floating-point numbers subject to rounding errors.  They are treated an inexact floating-point numbers if the matrix is entered with entries like `0.1` instead of `1/10`.

To get an result equivalent to the "human interpretation" of the problem, one can try the option `Tolerance` with [`RowReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RowReduce.html) (q.v.).

```
mat = {{-0.1, 0.1, 2}, {0.3, 0.2, 0.7}, {0, 0.5, 6.7}};
RowReduce[mat, Tolerance -> 10^-15]
(*
  {{1,   0., -6.6},
   {0,   1,  13.4},
   {0,   0,   0}}
*)
```

Without tolerance (V11.2 MacOS):

```
RowReduce[mat]
```

> RowReduce::luc: Result for RowReduce of badly conditioned matrix {{-0.1,0.1,2.},{0.3,0.2,0.7},{0.,0.5,6.7}} may contain significant numerical errors.

```
(*
  {{1,  0., 0.},
   {0,  1,  0.},
   {0,  0,  1}} 
*)
```

This is different from what @ilian reports for Linux.
The docs say that the setting for `Tolerance` in `RowReduce` is `Automatic`.  Perhaps the default tolerance has changed from version to version.

Comment: I am using Version 11.2 Windows x64 and I do not need to specify tolerance. I get the correct answer by just using `RowReduce[mat]`. I  understand what you are saying though. However, as Chip states, I think this is a W|A bug.

Comment: @user372003 Yes, W|A has a different audience in mind than *Mathematica*. But this site is a site about *Mathematica*, not W|A. -- I think it's odd, though, that we're getting different results on Macs than on Windows/Linux.